# Show that the real part and imaginary part of a solution of a differential equation are also real solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

Im a bit confused with this exercise because Im not sure what I must show here.

> Suppose $b,c\in\Bbb R$ and $z\in C^2(\Bbb R,\Bbb C)$ solves $\ddot u+b\dot u+cu=0$. Show that $\Re (z)$ and $\Im (z)$ are real solutions of $\ddot u+b\dot u+cu=0$.

This is my work: $$\ddot u+b\dot u+cu=0\,\land\, x:=\begin{bmatrix}u\\\dot u\end{bmatrix}\implies \dot x=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-c&-b\end{bmatrix}x$$

where $x\in C^1(\Bbb R,\Bbb C^2)$. Because $\Bbb C\cong \Bbb R^2$ as real vector spaces we can write

$$\begin{align}\begin{bmatrix}\Re(\dot u)&\Im(\dot u)\\\Re(\ddot u)&\Im(\ddot u)\end{bmatrix}&=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-c&-b\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\Re(u)&\Im(u)\\\Re(\dot u)&\Im(\dot u)\end{bmatrix}\\&=\begin{bmatrix}\Re(\dot u)&\Im(\dot u)\\-c\Re(u)-b\Re(\dot u)&-c\Im(u)-b\Im(\dot u)\end{bmatrix}\end{align}$$

from where we can conclude the assertion of the exercise equating coefficients of both matrices.

---

Im not sure if this is enough to show the statement of the exercise because Im using the fact that $\Bbb C\cong \Bbb R^2$ as real vector spaces, however $\Bbb C$ is a complex vector space. In other words: I dont understand clearly what must be shown in this exercise.

Comment: What you need is to identify $z$ as a vector function. $z(t) = u(t) + iv(t)$, and $u,v \in C^2(\mathbb R)$. And $\dot{z}(t) = u'(t) + iv'(t)$, $\ddot{z}(t) = u''(t) + iv
''(t)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this can be done simply using the following two properties of the equation
$$
\ddot{u} + b\dot{u} + cu = 0.
$$

1. If $u$ is a solution, then so is the complex conjugate $\bar{u}$.  This follows from the fact that $b,c\in \mathbb{R}$.
2. Linear combinations of solutions are still solutions.

The statement you want now follows from $\Im(u) = \frac{1}{2}(u - \bar{u})$ and $\Re(u) = \frac{1}{2}(u + \bar{u})$.

Comment: why is the complex conjugate also a solution?

Comment: Take the complex conjugate of both sides of the equation.  Observe that $\bar{\dot{u}} = \dot{\bar{u}}$ (this can be seen from the definition of the derivative, for example), and that $\bar{cu} = \bar{c}\bar{u} = c\bar{u}$, since $c$ is real.